# Stopping a running scheduled task in shopware6

Tags: shopware6

I would like to know how to stop a running scheduled task in shopware 6.
We have some huge integrations and they can be running for several hours updating +500K products.
This I would like to be able to stop if I see that the job is not running as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the table `scheduled_task` for the task you want to deactivate and change the value of the column `status` to `inactive`.

Programmatically:

```php
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('name', 'name_of_task'));
// scheduled_task.repository
$taskId = $this->scheduledTaskRepository->searchIds($criteria, $context)->firstId();

$this->scheduledTaskRepository->update([
    [
        'id' => $taskId,
        'status' => ScheduledTaskDefinition::STATUS_INACTIVE,
    ],
], $context);
```

Comment: My task has status scheduled, even though it is still running in the background on the server. Have tried to update the status in DB directly to "inactive" with no luck..
I have updated the database directly with the status "inactive" as the constant declares. This is not stopping the task from executing.

Comment: Obviously this will only prevent it from running continuously when the next cycle is due. If the current cycle is still running you'll have to kill the process.

Comment: This is also what i figured . is there a smart way of determining this process running?

Comment: Assuming you're running the CLI worker: `ps -A | grep "messenger:consume"`